# PHP7 oAuth request fail

Tags: php, oauth

I have a working login process using BitBucket APIs with oAuth that I'm trying to migrate to php7.

On PHP 5.6 it works fine, I then upgraded the server to PHP7 using this page's information https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-upgrade-to-php-7-on-centos-7

I also upgraded the oAuth pecl package version to use the new 2.0.0 which is made for PHP7.
The oAuth request stopped working and returns "Invalid request token."

I tried to uninstall oAuth package 2.0.0 and reinstall 1.2.3, but the install fails with

```
In file included from /var/tmp/oauth/oauth.c:14:0:
/var/tmp/oauth/php_oauth.h:35:40: fatal error: ext/standard/php_smart_str.h: No such file or directory
#include "ext/standard/php_smart_str.h"
```

Which seems to be a common error of trying to install package made for PHP 5.x on PHP7 since they renamed php_smart_str to php_smart_string (according to this bug report on the phpredis package github https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis/issues/682#issuecomment-163743879 )

I think maybe there were changes in the oAuth package that make it fail since 1.2.3, but I see no information about it in the documentation.

Here's the code

```
<?php
include 'includes/includes.php';
$req_url = 'https://bitbucket.org/api/1.0/oauth/request_token';
$authurl = 'https://bitbucket.org/api/1.0/oauth/authenticate';
$acc_url = 'https://bitbucket.org/api/1.0/oauth/access_token';
$api1_url = 'https://bitbucket.org/api/1.0/';
$api2_url = 'https://bitbucket.org/api/2.0/';

$callback_url="http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']."/bitbucket_login.php";

$conskey = 'mykey';
$conssec = 'mysecret';

session_start();
if(empty($_SESSION['user']))
{
    // In state=1 the next request should include an oauth_token.
    // If it doesn't go back to 0
    if(!isset($_GET['oauth_token']) && $_SESSION['state']==1) $_SESSION['state'] = 0;
    try {
        $oauth = new OAuth($conskey,$conssec,OAUTH_SIG_METHOD_HMACSHA1,OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_AUTHORIZATION);
        $oauth->enableDebug();
        if(!isset($_GET['oauth_token']) && !$_SESSION['state']) 
        {           
            $request_token_info = $oauth->getRequestToken($req_url,$callback_url);
            $_SESSION['secret'] = $request_token_info['oauth_token_secret'];
            $_SESSION['state'] = 1;
            header('Location: '.$authurl.'?oauth_token='.$request_token_info['oauth_token']);
            exit;
        } 
        else if($_SESSION['state']==1) 
        {
            $oauth->setToken($_GET['oauth_token'],$_SESSION['secret']);
            $access_token_info = $oauth->getAccessToken($acc_url);  //fails here
            $_SESSION['state'] = 2;
            $_SESSION['token'] = $access_token_info['oauth_token'];
            $_SESSION['secret'] = $access_token_info['oauth_token_secret'];
        }
        $oauth->setToken($_SESSION['token'],$_SESSION['secret']);

        if($_SESSION['state']==2)
        {
            //Get the info and do stuff
        }
    } 
    catch(OAuthException $E) 
    {
        print_r($E);
    }
}
?>
```